# Handling ASP postbacks from Javascript Widget

Tags: asp.net, javascript, vb.net, postback

I am trying to make a small, data-driven widget that is populated with data from a database on the fly.  I can load it initially just fine, but when the index of an ASP DropDownMenu is changed, the widget returns a 404.

This could be a symptom of how I am using the Javascript, or how I am using the ASP.  I honestly don't know for sure.

Javascript: http://pastebin.com/f127d6b84
ASP: http://pastebin.com/f38c73708
VB.NET codebehind: http://pastebin.com/f7881a903

Answer (score 1):

If the postback is returning 404, I'd look at the url that you're sending the postback to.

```
http://webwidgetstest.reeceandnichols.com/rDeskWidgetMLSt.aspx?agentname=jendene
```

Comment: It's the same url that I'm sending the initial request to, and the initial request works.  I apologize, but could I ask you to be more verbose?  I don't understand.

Also, the Request here is supposed to be sanitized by the page this will be used on. (that is what i've been told anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Also your widget has some security issues going on, namely SQL Injection.

> Dim SelectString As String = "select
>   ListingNumber, ListingSearchHitCount,
>   ListingDetailHitCount,
>   VirtualTourHitCount from
>   FNIS.dbo.ListingHitCountCurrent,
>   RAN.dbo.Heartland_Residential where
>   Heartland_Residential.LIST_AGENT_1_ID
>   = '" & Request("agentname") & "' and Heartland_Residential.MLS_Number =
>   FNIS.dbo.ListingHitCountCurrent.ListingNumber
>   and Heartland_Residential.Status =
>   'A'"

This inline SQL statement is not parameterizing the Request("agentname") field.

Comment: This is supposed to be santizied anyway, but you're right that I shouldn't really rely on others for that.  I went ahead and used a regular expression to sanitize the data. Anything not alphanumeric is stripped now.